# Blade conditional statements

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have several models.  Each model has a create and edit page.  If the model has not been created yet, I need to display its create page.  If it has been created, I need to show its edit page.

So far I have this which works

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    @if (is_null($project->projectType))
        @include ('projects.partials.projectTypesCreate')
    @else
        @include ('projects.partials.projectTypesEdit')
    @endif

    @if (is_null($project->projectData))
        @include ('projects.partials.projectDataCreate')
    @else
        @include ('projects.partials.projectDataEdit')
    @endif

    @if (is_null($project->projectTesting))
        @include ('projects.partials.projectTestingCreate')
    @else
        @include ('projects.partials.projectTestingEdit')
    @endif
</div>
```

Now, the above is not the prettiest, to many conditional statements in my opinion.  What makes this worse is the fact that I need to display things in order.  By this I mean that if projectType is null,
only projectTypesCreate should be displayed.  If it is not null. projectTypesEdit and  projectDataCreate should be displayed, and so on.

To accomplish this I could potentially do something like so

```
@if (is_null($project->projectType))
    @include ('projects.partials.campaignTypes')
@else
    @include ('projects.partials.campaignTypesEdit')
@endif

@if (!is_null($project->projectType) && is_null($project->projectData))
    @include ('projects.partials.projectDataCreate')
@else
    @include ('projects.partials.projectDataEdit')
@endif

@if (!is_null($project->projectData) && is_null($project->projectTesting))
    @include ('projects.partials.projectTestingCreate')
@else
    @include ('projects.partials.projectTestingEdit')
@endif
```

Once again though, it is getting a bit clunky and it is not accurate as to what I need because the edit page will display when the condition fails.

So really I am just after some advice as to how to best handle this situation.  I need to determine what view to display for each model, whilst at the same time displaying views sequentially.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single `$action` variable that holds the action you want to do, then use that in your `@include` statements:

```php
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    @php($action = is_null($project->projectType) ? 'Create' : 'Edit')

    @include('projects.partials.projectTypes'.$action)
    @include('projects.partials.projectData'.$action)
    @include('projects.partials.projectTesting'.$action)
</div>
```

Comment: I like the @php, I see that is new in 5.2.  The only problem with the above is that in only checks projectType.  If projectType is null, then nothing else should display.  The views need to be sequential based on whether the previous model is null or not.

Comment: @kate_hudson - oh right. I missed the fact that you're doing different checks for each one. In that case, I don't think there's much you can do to improve the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at RESTful routing in laravel. For one line in your routes file, several routes will be generated to allow you to perform CRUD operations on a model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Then if you need to reuse form elements you could create partials that are included on multiple views. Its a bit more work to set up but is easy to edit later on.