# Does PHP have an equivalent of ASP.NET Placeholder?

Tags: php

ASP.NET has a <asp:Placeholder> feature. For example...

```
// Server side C# Code.
myph.Visible = flag;

<!-- Later in the HTML section. -->
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="myph">
    HTML goes here.
</asp:Placeholder>
```

If the "Visible" property is set to true, the HTML inside is sent to the client. If false, the HTML is removed. The contents might have more server side <% %> code inside which is also included/removed depending on the flag.

I am porting an ASP.NET project to PHP. Does PHP have a way to mark-up large blocks of HTML (that uses small <?php echo ?> blocks inside) and flag to include/remove them elsewhere?

I'm hoping the answer isn't to use - if (flag) echo "lots of html"

Comment: No, you a switch case instead :-)

Comment: Where would you flag this elsewhere and how. You could perhaps use an array to echo it?

Comment: in php You can use frameworks (laravel) and then define that visible param and when calling rendering of layout You can pass it and inside of block You can check for flag.

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976413/blade-conditional-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some templating engine (Smarty, Twig, ...) to keep php code and html separated. But if you want to use inline php, just use

```
<?php
$block_visible = false;
?>

rest of your code here 

<?php 
if ( $block_visible ) { 
   ?>
    .... your code here ...
   <?php
} 
?>

or this one (to avoid curly braces)

<?php if ($block_visible) : ?>
  Your html here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: { } blocks can span between <?php ?> blocks? This changes everything! Thank you.

Comment: @billpg yes, they can. But I still recommend you to use some templating engine - its not so hard to learn and helps you to keep your code much cleaner ...

Comment: I'm converting a simple ASPX website, so I don't really want to make wide detours into technologies I'm unfamiliar with.